# Workfront (AtTask): Creating tasks via API using cURL

Tags: php, curl, workfront-api

I have built a form in PHP that submits via AJAX to a script that needs to post to the Workfront API to create a new task in a generic catch-all project.

When I put the following URL + Query in the browser (Chrome) address bar it did successfully create the the task, so now I need to adapt it to work in PHP:
https://MY-DEPT-NAME.preview.workfront.com/attask/api/v9.0/task/?name=New%20Task&description=This%20is%20my%20wonderful%20shiney%20new%20task&method=POST&apiKey=8ffskq9hj3q0swnzi6z1ixf9tl8qbop8&projectID=5b6358d7002b1b5c69342a098d752158

Here is the code I have, based partially on Workfront sample code in GitHub. Can you see what I am missing or doing wrong? (The name and description will be replaced with input from the form.)

```
    $url = "https://MY-DEPT-NAME.preview.workfront.com/attask/api/v9.0/task/";
    $data = array(
        'name' => 'My New Task',
        'description' => 'This is my wonderful shiney new task',
        'method' => 'POST',
        'apiKey' => '8ffskq9hj3q0swnzi6z1ixf9tl8qbop8',
        'projectID' => '5b6358d7002b1b5c69342a098d752158'
        );

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    if ($data){
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    }

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    var_dump( $result );

    curl_close( $curl );
    var_dump( $curl );
```

The result I am currently getting from those var_dump's is:
 "bool(false) resource(1) of type (Unknown)"

Comment: What happens if you set $data equal to the string that you use in your URL (everything after the question mark) instead of an array?

Comment: Add `if ($result === false) { echo curl_error($curl); }` after you `curl_exec`

Comment: Thank you all for your help:
@BrianR: I got the same result as with the array in the above code.

Comment: @MER: The error message is "error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol versionbool(false)."   Since that has to do with SSL, I changed the https: to http: and got "Temporary Redirect" as the response.

Comment: You may need to upgrade OpenSSL on your server.

Comment: Thanks, I researched that error and am leaning toward the same conclusion.  I don't have access to the server, so I passed that on to our IT team.

Comment: Workfront switched their SSL implementation a while back. They now require TLS1.1 to connect. Ensure that curl is communicating with that protocol.

Comment: @BrianR - Thanks.  Our IT team setup another dev site with PHP 7.3 and TLS1.3. I copied my test code to that site.  Apparently I am connecting to Workfront, because I am not getting an error, however my response string is garbage characters, and my task still is not getting created.  

Here is the response:  `��VJ-*�/R��V�M-.NLOU�R��/UH,JU��/QH.-*J�+ɩT��OOOMQ��S��o��7`

Comment: You can ignore the above comment.  After some troubleshooting and googling, I got it to work with the data concatenated into a string instead of an array.  :)